# Project a vector onto the plane of another vector

Tags: vectors

I have three $3D$ vectors, $v_M1$ $v_M2$ and $v_E$, and I need to project $v_E$ to $v_F$ so that it is on the same plane as $v_M1$ and $v_M2$. So something like this:

[image]

I know I can get the normal of the plane by taking the cross product of $v_M1$ and $v_M2$, but what do I do from there?

This is one of those annoying situations where I know what I want, but I'm not sure how to express it. Hopefully I'm using the right terms so that this makes sense...

Comment: One vector (in this case $v_M$) is not enough to determine a plane. You must have two noncollinear vectors. Or alternatively the normal vector to the plane.

Comment: OK, that's what I was afraid of. I guess I'll have to rethink this problem then. Thank you.

Comment: I updated the question by adding another vector so it's actually possible to get the normal of the plane. Where do I go from there?

Comment: the cross product gives the direction of the  willing plane

Comment: @mwomath I don't know what that means. Are you talking about the cross of $v_M1$ and $v_M2$? Isn't that the normal of the plane that those two vectors make?

Comment: $v_E \times v_F$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a very simple and short description of how to find the projection of a vector onto a plane, once you have the normal to that plane: http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=MathApps%2FProjectionOfVectorOntoPlane

I understand from your question that you know how to find the normal, right?

Comment: Yeah, that'll do just fine. Thanks!